# How to construct a deterministic trading model based on a loess (local regression) model?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, regression

Given data that has been fit to a loess model, can you make reliable decisions on future trades given a good past fit? Has anyone here done so and can give an example of their use case?

I am yet to decide what data set to use.

Comment: Sounds like you have a hammer and are searching for a nail. The data should inform the model choice. It's a mistake to choose a model and then search for data to apply it to, because "all models are wrong".

Answer (score 1):

I've been testing trading systems with lowess for a long time and have yet to find something that works.  Lowess is a adaptive, so it will change with the addition of future bars ( it is the best fit taking into account past and future data points).  If you plot a lowess on a chart, it is a perfect fit...not so much in real time.